# Is it possible to brute force a single smaller variable in $\operatorname{HMAC-SHA512}(k, a\ ||\ b\ ||\ c\ ||\ d)$?

Tags: hmac

Given $c' = \operatorname{HMACSHA512}(k, a\ ||\ b\ ||\ c\ ||\ d)$ and the 32-bit integers $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ is it feasible to alter $b$ and produce a valid MAC under the unknown key?

I understand that typically it wouldn't be, but I am mostly wondering if it's possible with 4 small independent inputs being used.

Would it change anything if I could observe many MACs over time with all variables constant except one?

Comment: It works fine in your case, since a,b,c,d are all fixed length (even all-but-one of them being fixed-length would suffice), but _in general_, concatenation does not necessarily suffice, since for example ​ ​ ​ 01 || 0 ​ = ​ 0 || 10 ​ ​ . ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Indeed! I noticed that this would pose a problem for a different thing I was working on. Someone recommended using a separator value like a comma.

Comment: Another option is using a [prefix-free code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code). ​ ​

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is is feasible to alter `b` and produce a valid MAC under the unknown key?

We most certainly hope not.  The fundamental security property of a MAC is that, even if that attacker can get a huge number of valid (Message, MAC) pairs (where he gets to choose the messages), he still is unable to generate a MAC for a message he has not seen.  This fundamental property doesn't change just because the inputs are 'small'.

We believe that HMAC-SHA512 is a secure MAC (assuming an unguessable key); hence we believe that it is secure in your case.

Comment: I assumed this was the case. I figured it would not make any difference if there were small independent variables in the message that were changing in minor ways versus the message changing completely.